# Algo falla en mi programa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Veran, estoy haciendo un programa en Java con Hibernate en Netbeans.
Para ello, Tengo una clase llamada Profesor, la cual tiene este código:

```
package hibernar;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Profesor")
public class Profesor implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="nom")
    private String nom;
    @Column(name="ape1")
    private String ape1;
    @Column(name="ape2")
    private String ape2;

    public Profesor(){}

    public Profesor(int i, String n, String a, String p){
    id=i;
    nom=n;
    ape1=a;
    ape2=p;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getApe1() {
        return ape1;
    }

    public void setApe1(String ape1) {
        this.ape1 = ape1;
    }

    public String getApe2() {
        return ape2;
    }

    public void setApe2(String ape2) {
        this.ape2 = ape2;
    }
}
```

Tambien tengo un fichero llamado hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hibernate1</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hibernate1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="Hibernar/Profesor.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping class="Hibernar.Profesor"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Y por ultimo tenemos el fichero principal, llamado Hibernar:

```
package hibernar;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Hibernar{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Profesor profesor=new Profesor(101, "Juan", "Perez", "García"); 

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(profesor);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println(profesor.getApe1());
        session.close(); 

        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Se supone que esto tiene que almacenar a un profesor en la tabla y mostrar por pantalla su primer apellido, pero algo me falla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria que alguien me diga que hago mal.

Edito: Actualmente tengo así esta hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">daniel</property>
        <property name="connection.password">patochalado</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="hibernar.Profesor"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Y esto es el mensaje de error al ejecutarlo:

```
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.21.Final}
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate1]
feb 24, 2018 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=daniel, password=****}
Sat Feb 24 15:07:22 CET 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
feb 24, 2018 3:07:23 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
feb 24, 2018 3:07:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
feb 24, 2018 3:07:23 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: insert into Profesor (ape1, ape2, nom, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
feb 24, 2018 3:07:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
feb 24, 2018 3:07:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'hibernate1.profesor' doesn't exist
feb 24, 2018 3:07:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3079)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at hibernar.Hibernar.main(Hibernar.java:23)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate1.profesor' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186)
    ... 14 more
C:\Users\pcx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Me llama la atención la parte que dice "Table 'hibernate1.profesor' doesn't exist".

Parece ser que intenta conectarse con un programa llamado MySQL. Lo tengo instalado, pero me cuesta entender como lo manejo o como lo relaciono con Netbeans.
Aqui muestro una captura del programa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo ahi un esquema llamado hibernate1, aunque no tengo ninguna tabla Profesor.

Comment: Donde tienes el archivo Hibernar/Profesor.hbm.xml?

Comment: @Klaimmore No hay. Esto lo saque de unos apuntes y ahi estaba. Actualmente he quitado la referencia a ese fichero. Voy a actualizar.

Comment: El problema original era por que referenciabas un archivo de configuración inexistente, ahora tienes el problema de que usas un esquema vacio sin tablas por lo que no pilla la tabla referenciada por tu entidad `Profesor`

Answer (score 0):

Como no tienes tablas en tu esquema, puedes instruir a hibernate que las cree a partir de las entidades.

Agrega a tu configuración de hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: Pues sigue fallando. Ahora me sale esto: El atributo "value" se debe haber declarado para el tipo de elemento "property".

Comment: Debe ser por la sintaxis prueba con la modificación, basicamente en lugar de en un atributo value como cuerpo del tag property

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido por primera vez ejecutar el programa.
Para eso, me he ido a la base de datos interna del Netbeans y he creado ahi la tabla profesores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tras eso, ya he podido ejecutar con exito la tabla.
El problema es que me gustaria que no hiciera falta eso, sino que baste con que ponga la clase Profesor.